# How to lazy load items from mysql db like facebook and twitter (infinite scrolling)

Tags: php, mysql, lazy-loading

I know there are plugins to lazy load images. I have a coupon code site, on my category page for shoes in my DB I have 500 coupons that match. I don't want to display all 500 for obvious reasons. I only want to show 20 initially, and then as the user keeps scrolling down the page it loads more coupons. How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I've got the ajax call working. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "loadmore.php",
                    success: function(html){
                        if(html){
                            $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                        }else{
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

The problem I have now is how to get the right rows from the database everytime I scroll?

On the initial page load I'm doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblCoupons LIMIT 0,20
```

What should the mysql call look like in the loadmore.php file? I guess I need to increment a counter somehow....hmmm...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's one feature on the internet that I hope goes away... but here's the deal-

On page load, you grab like 100 results or however many you want, then spit those into a container. On load, you use jquery to log the height of the content area on your site. Set the starting index so you know what to query for (obviously send the relevant page data in your ajax call), fetch the screen size and wait for scroll. On scroll you check the scrollTop offset plus window size to see if the user is at the bottom of the page within a reasonable threshold - in this case around 100 pixel tolerance. Make the ajax call and then append the results.

```
var screen_height = $('body').height();
var cur-y = $(window).scrollTop();
var screen = $(window).height();
var cur_index = 0;
```

Then apply a scroll listener to body...

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + screen >= (screen_height - 100))
    {
      // make an ajax call to your server and fetch the next 100, then update
      //some vars
        $.ajax({
            url: "your_script.php",
            data: {cur_index:cur_index},
            success: function(){
                cur_index += 1;
                screen_height = $('body').height();

               // append content to your container

            }
        });
    }
});
```

... basically.
This is not intended to be copy/ paste. but more like a generic guide to how I have done it in the past. You should also set provisions so this only fires once per intended event since .scroll() listens for any scroll movement.

hope it helps in some way.

Comment: That's actually pretty interesting: why do you think it should go away?

Comment: @3axap Joe - Because it's an involuntary action. You don't always know it's going to load, elements may jump a bit, it might cause a momentary lag in browser behavior, etc. I work for a web firm and it seems everyone was wanting lazy load like it was a buzz word. You can send analytics events on lazy load to see how few people scroll down far enough to trigger it, and how even fewer scroll down to trigger more. For the cost of development and provisions needed - like if they loaded 3 pages in, clicked an article, then hit back it would not be where they left off - it isn't worth the budget

Comment: Actually you may be right. Google after all don't do an endless roll of search results... for a reason. I asked because I am working on an online dictionary for a rare language and some searches that contain few characters produce a lot of information. One way to deal with it is to do lazy loading, another - split it into pages and yet another is to not do anything at all which is normal too albeit it may generate a huge page that's harder for the client to process. And I'm kinda torn on what method would be the most correct if we put web standards first. People have very different opinions...

Comment: Sounds like a chance to write some factoring algorithm based on common usage. Like words containing "ae" in english - "algae" is a lot more common than something like "faeries" in old world style. Maybe a weight relation, categorization? You could present tabs for common words vs everything else. Interesting situation though.

Comment: So in the end you advise to use tabs instead of splitting into pages et cetera? Basing this on experience I'm afraid that may confuse users. How about using slide-out/dynamically updated areas that feature top 5 results from 4 different dictionaries? Do you think it's a good idea? In the end factoring algorithms are great but there's still a problem of what we do with huge result sets...

Comment: No I didn't mean to use tabs. I'd say normal pagination is best. Tabs was more like an option for filtering if the algorithm produces results in a wide spread application, like common usage, etc.