# Speeding up responses from a database query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am running a `select * from table order by date desc` query using php on a mysql db server, where the table has a lot of records, which slows down the response time.

So, is there any way to speed up the response. If indexing is the answer, what all columns should I make indexes.

Comment: Use `limit` in your query & paginate your records.

Comment: Do you need every column?

Comment: Not so easy: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html

Comment: Hi @rikesh, have to display those records without pagination and all in one go

Comment: @DaveHogan ya i need every column

Comment: @user11085 - Than it is tough. I think you need to use some caching system (eg: memcached).

Comment: Also Check [Lazy Loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059773/how-to-lazy-load-items-from-mysql-db-like-facebook-and-twitter-infinite-scrolli). It may helps you,

Comment: @Rikesh will my server be down while i install and configure memcached?

Comment: @user11085 - Most probably not if all goes well. But cannot be sure it may affect your server if anything goes wrong while installing or configure memcahed.

Answer (score 0):

An index speeds up searching when you have a WHERE clause or do a JOIN with fields you have indexed. In your case you don't do that: You select all entries in the table. So using an index won't help you.

Are you sure you need all of the data in that table? When you later filter, search or aggregate this data in PHP, you should look into ways to do that in SQL so that the database sends less data to PHP.

Comment: thanks for your answer. and yes I need all data cause its used in a mobile app and I cant change the app code now, only the backend. And the mobile app is coded to get all data at once.

Comment: Would it be possible to store the data in a different way?

Comment: Then all you can do is buying a faster database server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use caching system.
the best i know [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) It's really great to speed up your application and it's not using database at all.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't speed anything up using software.

Reason: you're selecting entire contents of a table and you said it's a large table.

What you could do is cache the data, but not using Memcache because it's got a limit on how much data it can cache (1 MB per key), so if your data exceeds that - good luck using Memcache to cache a huge result set without coming up with an efficient scheme of maintaining keys and values.

Indexing won't help because you haven't got a WHERE clause, what could happen is that you can speed up the order by clause slightly. Use EXPLAIN EXTENDED before your query to see how much time is being spent in transmitting the data over the network and how much time is being spent in retrieving and sorting the data from the query.

If your application requires a lot of data in order for it to work, then you have these options:

- Get a better server that can push the data faster
- Redesign your application because if it requires so much data in order to run, it might not be designed with efficiency in mind

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing Query is a big topic and beyond the scope this question

here are some **highlight** that will boost you select statement

- Use proper Index
- Limit the number records
- use the column name that you require (instead writing `select * from table` use `select col1, col2 from table`)

to limit query for large offset is little tricky in mysql
this select statement for large offset will be slow because it have to process large set of data

```
SELECT * FROM table order by whatever LIMIT m, n;
```

to optimize this query here is simple solution

```
select A.* from table A 
  inner join (select id from table order by whatever limit m, n) B
  on A.id = B.id
order by A.whatever
```