# Infinite Scroll For Message List. Like Facebook Messages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, infinite-scroll

My friends, I am having a trouble to load more messages when I scroll down. Initially I want latest messages. When the user scrolls, I want to load the another limited set of messages. When user scrolls again the next set loads. Similar to Facebook messages.

this is my code.

```
{
    <div id="msgboxfully" style ="height:345px; width:100%;overflow:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;display: flex;flex-direction: column-reverse;">
    <ul id="uuuut">
    <li id="jqmsglist">
    <div class="msg-shower_new">
    <img src="$msgs3frm_img}" />
    <div class="text-box" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <sh2><a class="msg-shower_new" href="./$msgs3frm_usn">$msgs3frm_usn</a></sh2> <sh1 style="float:right;line-height:35px;color:#a5a5a5;">$msgs3date}</sh1>
    </div>
    <div class="text-box" style="margin-top:-2px;">
    <sh1>$msgs3msg</sh1>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li></ul></div> 
}
```

this code is looping and i have 100+ messages in one conversion.
please help me

Comment: Please be more specific about what you need help with.

Comment: You need to listen to the scroll event and when you've scrolled low enough send an AJAX request to retrieve more messages. There's probably online tutorials that explain how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lazy load items from mysql db like facebook and twitter (infinite scrolling)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059773/how-to-lazy-load-items-from-mysql-db-like-facebook-and-twitter-infinite-scrolli)

Comment: first time show only limited massages and when scroll down showing other messages